# Scrappy python3 error 403(forbidden) при запросе к https://www.autotrader.co.uk/

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

При попытке распарсить autotrader с использованием фрэйма scrappy столкнулся с ошибкой 403, которую никак не могу побороть - уже и user agent подкинул и погуглил подобные ошибки ..ничего  не берёт
Ошибка:

```
2020-07-14 18:08:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-14 18:08:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-14 18:08:15 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-14 18:08:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?postcode=ec1a1aa&make=TESLA> (referer: None)
2020-07-14 18:08:15 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?postcode=ec1a1aa&make=TESLA>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Код:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request


class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?postcode=ec1a1aa&make=TESLA'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
                   'Referer': 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/'}
        # smth = response.css('.paginationMini__count::text').getall()
        yield Request(self.start_urls, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Нужна помощь именно со Scrappy! bs и requests не подойдут

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря не знаком со scrapy но через bs4 и requests этот сайт парсится весьма просто
Ниже первый этап обработки данной Вами страницы. Собирает блоки описаний (всего 272 шт.) Со всех 25 страниц результата.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=relevance&postcode=ec1a1aa&radius=1500&make=TESLA&page=%s'


def scrape_page(page_num: int = 1):
    response = requests.get(url % page_num)
    pages_qty = 1
    page_units_list = []
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        pages_count_tag = soup.find('li', class_='paginationMini__count')
        if pages_count_tag:
            pages_qty = max(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', pages_count_tag.text)))
        res = soup.find_all('article', class_='search-listing')
        if res:
            page_units_list = res

    return page_units_list, pages_qty


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vehicles, pages = scrape_page()
    for page in range(2, pages + 1):
        vehicles += scrape_page(page)[0]
```

В результате получаем список `vehicles` тэгов содержащих html код вот этих блоков
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вам останется написать функцию обработки для них.

Comment: знаю, через bs легко и сам распарсил. Тут суть именно в фрэйме, ибо он понадобится в другом проекте. Сбор тэсл - это так, ознакомление сдокументацией и проблемами

Comment: Вас блокируют на основании пользовательского агента. Вам нужен прокси.

Comment: @Wertartem, скорее всего писали Вы не мне, но справедливости ради, тот скрипт, что сверху прошел по всей выборке из 25 страниц 5 раз подряд и вернул корректную информацию, ни разу не споткнувшись

Comment: @Wertartem , большое спасибо, похоже это решение моих проблем

Comment: Скрипт у вас замечательный но 25 страниц это "пыль" Вы 25 тысяч сделайте.

Comment: @Wertartem, автор не ставил такой задачи. При небольшом напилинге он 500 000 сделает

Comment: Я отметил Ваш ответ как полезный. Спасибо что напомнили о "небольшом напилинге" думаю он решит все проблемы с ошибкой 403.

Comment: @Wertartem - ни прокси, ни авто подбор user agent-в не помог. Хоть и статус запроса стал 200, но функция parse будто мертва и даже на банальный print не реагирует. Пользовался scrapy-proxy-pool и scrapy-user-agent

Comment: нужен код - попробуйте новый проект scrapy startproject [project]  - запустите scrapy shell [ваш url] посмотрите ответ и как забирает на странице. + обычно ваш ip часа через 2 они достаю из бана. + посмотрите сколько они дают вам скачать страниц до бана + уменьшить скорость -- они могут думать что вы их атакуете.